# Find Max Amount and second max amount for each listings

Tags: mysql

I have a table of bids that I want to query information.
Table structure is:  id, item_id, price, date, user_id
Many user place bids on this table.  I need to find a list of all the item_id with the max   price received and also the second max price receive for the same item.

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT item_id, MAX(price) as MAX, (SELECT MAX(price) FROM TABLE GROUP BY item_id, LIMIT 1,1) FROM TABLE WHERE date > 2013-01-01 GROUP BY item_id
```

What am I missing

This is the result I am getting

```
item_id    MAX    USER_ID    MAX(PRICE)
1          17222     122       22500
2          15888     161       22500
```

For all my next items, The second is always  22500, how can I get the real second value for the second best bid?

Comment: Does each row has a unique id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is tested. Try it:

```
SELECT t1.item_id, 
MAX(t1.price) AS MAX1, 
(SELECT t2.price FROM TABLE AS t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id ORDER BY t2.price DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS MAX2 
FROM TABLE AS t1 
WHERE t1.date > 2013-01-01 
GROUP BY t1.item_id
```

Comment: THis is promissing.  Seems to be working.  I have another problem, if I want to join other table to this, I seem to be getting always the same MAX1=MAX2   here is what I have written to try to add more info on my table:

Comment: OK, This is getting to what I want, I get the correct bids.  I need to add information to my query, I need the names of the people who placed the bids as well.  I have a field called user_id in the table.  I want to LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.mid = t1.user_id and same thing for t2.user_id LEFT JOIN tp profile.mid.     I get names, but they do not correspond to the users who placed the bids

Comment: I added a user_id in my SELECT statement to view the user id, but I seem to be generating tho first user_id who placed a bid in my listing and not the corresponding max bid user_id, any idea?

Comment: You need to add another (select userid from the same table with MAX1 = MAX(price)) AS USERID and left join the user table ON returned USERID = user_table.userid

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative mechanism, using a `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick.  Presumably, you also want the user with the maximum price, which your query does not do.  Try this:

```
select item_id, max(price) as maxprice,
       substring_index(group_concat(user_id order by price desc), ',', 1) as user_id,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(price order by price desc),
                                       ',', 2),
                       ',', -1) as secondprice
from t
group by item_id;
```

Comment: It seems to be giving me the max price, but the second price is not right.  Seems to be giving me the lowest price or the second lowest price.

Comment: @maphaneuf . . . Sorry about that.  My fingers didn't type everything I was thinking.  I left outer the `order by` in the `group_concat()`.